# RegEx with counting digits and allow special chars

Tags: regex

I've done some searching but cant find the right regex.

i would like a regex for a text that only contains digits, whitespaces and plus signs.
like: [0-9 +]

But with a min/max limit for only the digits in that text.

My suggestions ended up with something like this:

```
    ^[0-9 \+](?=(.*[0-9]){5,8})$
```

Should be OK:

- "123 456 7"
- "12345"
- "+ 123 456 78"

Should not be ok:

- "123456789"
- "+ 124 578a"
- "+123456789"

Anyone got a solution that might do the trick?

Edit:

I can see that i was to short on my explanation what i'm aiming for.

My regex conditions should be:

- Must include between 5-8 digits
- Allow whitespaces and plus signs

Comment: Why don't you do it in two steps? First check that it only contains the desired characters and then count the digits.

Comment: i'm using a service that only have one field for regex conditions. :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing from your own regex that between 5 and 8 digits in a row without a whitespace in between are allowed. If that's true, than the following regex might do the trick (example written in Python). It allows single digit groups being between 5 and 8 digits long. If there is more than one group, it allows each group to have exactly 3 digits except for the last group which can be between 1 and 3 digits long. One single plus sign on the left is optional.

Are you parsing phone numbers? :)

```
In [176]: regex = re.compile(r"""
                 ^                  # start of string
                 (?: \+\s )?        # optional plus sign followed by whitespace
                 (?:
                     (?: \d{3}\s )+ # one or more groups of three digits followed by whitespace
                     \d{1,3}        # one group of between one and three digits
                     |              # ALTERNATIVE
                     \d{5,8}        # one group of between five and eight digits
                 )
                 $                  # end of string
                 """, flags=re.X)

# --- MATCHES ---
In [177]: regex.findall('123 456 7')
Out[177]: ['123 456 7']

In [178]: regex.findall('12345')
Out[178]: ['12345']

In [179]: regex.findall('+ 123 456 78')
Out[179]: ['+ 123 456 78']

In [200]: regex.findall('12345678')
Out[200]: ['12345678']

# --- NON-MATCHES ---
In [180]: regex.findall('123456789')
Out[180]: []

In [181]: regex.findall('+ 124 578a')
Out[181]: []

In [182]: regex.findall('+123456789')
Out[182]: []

In [198]: regex.findall('123')
Out[198]: []

In [24]: regex.findall('1234 556')
Out[24]: []
```

Comment: Hi there, sorry for late answer.
Yes, i'm trying to parse phone numbers. :)

I can see that i was to short on my explanation what i'm aiming for. The group conditions isn't needed at all.

I've got a bunch of phone numbers. My conditions should be:
- Must include between 5-8 digits
- Can contain whitespace and plus sign

Answer (score 0):

You were very close - you need to anchor the lookahead to the start of input, and add a second *negative* lookahead for the upper bound of the quantity of digits:

```
^(?=(.*\d){5,8})(?!(.*\d){9,})[\d +]+$
```

Also, fyi you don't need to escape the plus sign within the character class, and `[0-9]` is `\d`

Comment: No, since you allow `.*` in your lookahead it will also match on longer numbers [Regexr](http://regexr.com?33ccr)

Comment: This doesn't match any of the examples given by the OP.

Comment: @stema Finally figured out how to fix my regex. I tested it on regexpal and it passes all examples given by OP

Comment: @PeterStahl Finally figured out how to fix my regex. I tested it on regexpal and it passes all examples given by OP

Comment: @Bohemian Your regex is not as strict as mine. It allows groups consisting of more than three digits without whitespace in between, e.g. `1234 567`. Mine only allows groups of up to three digits. But the OP has not specified what he wants. I suppose he wants to parse phone numbers and they are usually formatted as 3-digit-groups. Also, your regexp accepts more than one `+` which is probably not correct.

Comment: @peter There is no mention or suggestion in the question of digit grouping size, so any limit is irrelevant. The same goes for the plus sign. The question does not even mention or suggest that it's trying to check a telephone number. The question was quite specific, and this answer answers the question as posed.

Comment: @Bohemian I was guessing the grouping size because of the regex the OP provided himself. But never mind, maybe he will tell us.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
^(?:[ +]*[0-9]){5}(?:(?:[ +]*[0-9])?){3}$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?33cco)

The first group `(?:[ +]*[0-9]){5}` are the 5 minimum digits, with any amount of spaces and plus before, the second part `(?:(?:[ +]*[0-9])?){3}` matches the optional digits, with any amount of spaces and plus before.

Comment: I guess the OP wants to parse phone numbers. Therefore, an arbitrary amount of plus signs is probably not correct.